# Can you cast banishment on yourself?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, planes, targeting

Can you cast [*banishment*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/banishment) on yourself from a non-native plane, as a way of returning to your native plane?

Comment: Related: [If I cast Banishment on myself while in a demiplane, where exactly do I exit?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/116960/if-i-cast-banishment-on-myself-while-in-a-demiplane-where-exactly-do-i-exit)

Answer (score 65, accepted):

From the [Basic Rules](http://media.wizards.com/2014/downloads/dnd/PlayerDnDBasicRules_v0.2_PrintFriendly.pdf), p.80:

> ### Targeting Yourself
>
> If a spell targets a creature of your choice, you can 
>   choose yourself, unless the creature must be hostile or 
>   specifically a creature other than you. If you are in the 
>   area of effect of a spell you cast, you can target yourself.

It appears that, as long as you can see yourself, you're a legal target for *banishment* since it does not specify that it has to be a creature other than you.

If you were already on your own native plane and the spell successfully affected you, then at this point you would be sent to a harmless demiplane in which you would be incapacitated, immediately breaking concentration and returning you to the point at which you cast it upon yourself.

However, the incapacitation effect is *not* specified for creatures not on their native plane at the time of their banishment; You should be able to continue maintaining concentration for the remaining minute after sending yourself there, at which point it would be 'permanent'. (This may be a neat 'dodging' mechanic for if your environment suddenly becomes temporarily dangerous- banish yourself, and release concentration before it becomes 'permanent')

It may be worth houseruling that you have to succeed on a basic concentration check (constitution saving throw, DC 10) for shifting yourself via a method probably meant for banishing others, but that's not necessary by RAW.

---

Note that, [by RAW, you cannot choose to fail the saving throw](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/79000/23127).

Comment: Sage Advice (Jeremy Crawford) from Q4 2016 confirms that, if you're not in your native plane, you can cast Banishment on yourself to return there (albeit in an otherwise random location): https://www.sageadvice.eu/2016/12/01/can-you-cast-banishment-on-yourself/ .  This might be useful in an emergency, but if your native plane is anything like Earth it's surface is about 7/10 water, so you better know how to swim!