# Are there any official stats for a sheep?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, animals

Effect 77-78 of the wild magic surge table in the Player's Handbook states:

> You cast *polymorph* on yourself. If you fail the saving throw, you turn into a sheep for the spell's duration.

Polymorph's spell description then says:

> The target's game statistics, including mental ability scores, are replaced by the statistics of the chosen beast.

However, I'm unable to find the game statistics of a sheep, either in the Monster Manual or Appendix D of the Player's Handbook itself. Did I overlook something? Is there an official source of this creature's statistics?

Comment: Sidebar - Can you intentionally fail the saving throw if you WANT to be a sheep?

Comment: @Freiheit See: [Can you choose to fail a saving throw?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/47487/23970)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### *Storm King's Thunder* uses a modified goat statblock for sheep.

D&D Beyond includes a [sheep](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/sheep) statblock, for which it cites p. 142 of *Storm King's Thunder* as the source. Looking at that page of the adventure, [Grudd Haug area 9 (Stockyard)](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/skt/den-of-the-hill-giants#9Stockyard) says to use a modified version of the [goat](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/goat) statblock (basic rules, p. 138; SRD, p. 381) to represent sheep:

> Use the **goat** for the **sheep**, with the following changes:
>
> - It is a Small beast with 3 (1d6) hit points.
> - Its speed is 30 feet.
> - It lacks the Charge feature and any effective attacks.
> - Its challenge rating is 0 (0 XP).

Note that the goat statblock is already CR 0, but is normally worth 10 XP - presumably because it does actually have a ram attack and a Charge trait (ineffective though they may be). The sheep statblock no longer has this attack or trait, and its hit die is also slightly smaller so it has 1 less max HP on average. Per the ["Experience Points by Challenge Rating"](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/monsters#ExperiencePointsbyChallengeRating) table, CR 0 creatures can be worth either 0 or 10 XP (it's the only challenge rating for which more than one value is listed in the table).

That said, the [Wild Magic Surge](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/sorcerer#WildMagicSurge-381) table (PHB, p. 104) obviously wasn't written to reference an adventure that wasn't even out yet at the time the *Player's Handbook* was written (one which was released a few months after you posted your question). As [nitsua60's answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/83211/33569) says, the book itself acknowledges that it can't include statistics for every animal in the world, and leave it open for the DM to approximate something reasonable based on what's provided. Even without owning *Storm King's Thunder*, one could reasonably have decided to use the goat statblock (as-is or modified) to represent a sheep if needed - SKT simply explicitly codifies that advice for use in the adventure.

Answer (score 70):

### There <s>are</s> were no official stats for Sheep.

But we won't leave you hanging...

> **Other Animals.** A book of this size can't contain statistics for every animal inhabiting your D&D campaign world. However, you can use the stat block of one animal to represent another easily enough. For example, you can use the panther statistics to represent a jaguar, the giant goat statistics to represent a buffalo, and the hawk statistics to represent a falcon. (MM p.317)

So there it is, from the developers' mouths: if the stat isn't in here, feel free to grab something similar and re-skin it. Knowing almost nothing about either species I'd say grab a Goat (MM330) and run with it.

Comment: Seconding the suggestion of a goat -- the domestic sheep's wild ancestor (the mouflon) is basically an Old World equivalent to the bighorn sheep -- which is more goat-like than sheep-like if you ask most folks.

Answer (score -1):

***These stats are provided by a 3rd party, but appear to be appropriate for use:***

[Sheep](https://www.5esrd.com/gamemastering/monsters-foes/monsters-by-type/beasts/sheep/)
Medium Beast, Unaligned

Armor Class: 10
Hit Points 4 (1d8)
Speed: 30 ft.

STR DEX CON INT WIS CHA
12 (+1) 10 (0)  11 (0)  2 (-4)  10 (0)  5 (-3)
Senses: passive Perception 10
Languages: –
Challenge: 0 (10 XP)

Special Traits

Sure-Footed: A sheep has advantage on Strength and Dexterity saving throws made against effects that would knock it prone.
Actions

Hoof. Melee Weapon Attack: +3 to hit, reach 5 ft., one target. Hit: 3 (1d4+1) bludgeoning damage.
Bite. Melee Weapon Attack: +3 to hit, reach 5 ft., one target. Hit: 1 point of crushing damage.

Comment: I've edited in the source of your information to indicate the 3rd party source. Please edit if you think it deviates from your intent.