# Can you remove a blindfold using the Telekinesis spell?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, vision-and-light, blind

Suppose a Sorcerer with Subtle Spell is blindfolded, and has their hands tied behind their back. Could they Subtle cast [*telekinesis*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/telekinesis) to remove the blindfold?

The relevant part of the spell description:

> When you cast the spell, and as your action each round for the duration, you can exert your will on one creature or object **that you can see** within range, causing the appropriate effect below.

In short, do they see the blindfold when they open their eyes (even if the blindfold is pitch black)?

Comment: So it boils down to "can you see perfectly black item"?

Comment: Blindfold's don't have an existing ruleset, how is your DM (or you if you're the DM) ruling how it works? Does it give the Blinded condition? Or something else? Given your use of the "blind" tag, you seem to be directing that they are suffering from the 'blinded' condition.

Comment: Do you mean RAW, or something else? Consider adding a tag.

Comment: @WakiNadiVellir Not sure I understand what you're asking/recommending OP to do.

Comment: Is it an ordinary blindfold or a magical one?

Comment: Correct, @Molot.

Comment: @Mast: Ordinary.

Answer (score 37):

## Yes, but going by RAW you'd have to contest your own strength

The definition of "see" means you can visualise the target or include it in at least one of your sight senses; as the only thing blocking your normal sight is the blindfold, the blindfold is currently in your vision.

However, going by the rules as written, there's a hilarious wrinkle:

> If the object is worn or carried by a creature, you must make an ability check with your spellcasting ability contested by that creature's Strength check. If you succeed, you pull the object away from that creature and can move it up to 30 feet in any direction but not beyond the range of this spell.

As there is no listed exception for objects being worn *by the person casting Telekinesis*, you'd have to contest your own Strength check against your own spellcasting ability to be able to successfully remove the blindfold from yourself.

Of course, this is pretty ludicrous and I imagine most GMs would choose not to enforce that unless you'd really annoyed them that day. :P

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96957/discussion-on-answer-by-john-clifford-can-you-remove-a-blindfold-using-the-telek).

Comment: Of relevance to your answer: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/143402/can-a-player-choose-to-fail-a-spells-ability-check-contest

Answer (score 2):

## No, the PC is Blind

The problem here is that you have been blinded. I am making an assumption (but will update if the question clarifies) that the character is now blind based on the tag included in the question itself.

If they are blind, they can not see. It's not that they only see the blindfold, but that they cannot see at all. If they can't see, then they don't meet the spell's requirement.

Comment: That was my initial thought NautArch, but I would argue that the blindfold itself is an exception to the condition because it is the thing that's causing the condition in the first place. You can't see anything *past* the blindfold, but if your sight sense is still active and the only thing in its way is an object in front of you, I would say you're able to see the object. It does depend on how the GM mechanically implements the blindfold though, as you commented.

Comment: @JohnClifford There are no exceptions to the condition. If the condition applies, it applies. A DM can always rule differently, but you didn't state any different mechanic about the blindfold so I didn't apply anything.

Comment: Then I shall await OP clarifying and amend my answer to acknowledge yours as the right one if the blindfold is causing Blinded. :)

Comment: *the only thing in its way is an object in front of you, I would say you're able to see the object* - strictly speaking I don't think that's the case. If a blindfold is truly opaque, and fully covering your eyes, there will be no light "inside" it (between it and your character's eyes). Sight works by way of light hitting our eyes. There's no light to reflect off the "inside" surface of the blindfold to hit your eyes. So you can't see the blindfold.

Comment: @dwizum That assumes that real world physics operate the usual way in D&D, which isn't a valid assumption. Consider a blindfolded person with darkvision, for instance.

Comment: I can't see any rule that blindfold (regular, nonmagical) would bestow blinded condition. Also, seeing blindfold is an edge case. Like, you can't touch anyone wearing a straitjacket, but you are considered touching jacket itself, right? So, if your claim is supported by rules, please include a quote.

Comment: @molot my point was there is no rule for it, but OP tagged the question with Blind which are questions about the blinded condition. Until they give us more info or clarify, I'm going with their direction that the character is blinded. If they give us more info about their tables blindfold mechanics or remove the tag, that's the data we've got to work with

Comment: @NautArch: The tag is not necessarily a reference to the mechanical "blinded" condition (and certainly not specific to D&D 5e), but rather for questions about the state of being blind or blinded in-game in RPGs in general. Besides the system tag, it's generally best to rely on the body of the question rather than making assumptions about it solely based on the tags.

Comment: @V2Blast I had commented under the question asking for clarification because there is no 'blindfold' as an item with rules so we need to know how it 'works' in their game in order to answer that. In absence of more information, I went with the tags that OP used, which includes "For questions primarily related to situations involving states of blindness or blinded conditions in role-playing games." The body doesn't have the information here, so I used the tag they used to infer more. Maybe that's wrong, but until OP says otherwise, it's all I've got.

Comment: @AdmiralJota, i do not remember, but may be you can point me to place in rules, where physics, chemistry and math were redefined or made obsolete? Cause I assume DnD relies heavily on "defaults". You know, we breath air, we see through transparent, but opaque blocks vision. We walk like there is some gravity, temperature (or energy) decline has same direction as time etc.......

Answer (score -2):

### I would rule yes, they can

with a note below.

The requirement for exerting your will is that you can see the target, that is the blindfold. Unless you are in darkness, you would be able to see the blindfold. The amount of light needed to see the blindfold is open to the DM's ruling. As a general rule, you would be able to see the blindfold if at least the blindfold is within dim light area.

The blindfold being worn is actually not a concern, because you won't resist.

> **Note:** Stricter (and ridiculous) reading would require you to still perform the contest. The DM may grant advantage to spellcasting ability roll and disadvantage for strength roll for not resisting, though.

If the blindfold is secured with a knot, more realistic DM might consider whether you can't see the knot. Most of the times you can't see the knot, thus won't be able to untie the blindfold. You might still be able to remove the blindfold, though, if it's not tightly secured.

> **Note:** Stricter reading would disregard the position of knot. You can see the blindfold, so you can manipulate the knot wherever it is.

So, I would ask myself these questions:

1. Is the blindfold in darkness? If yes, the answer is **no.**
2. Is the blindfold secured with a knot? If yes, most likely the answer is **no**.
3. Else, **yes, you can** remove the blindfold.