# What would be a good ruling for "grabbing -> carrying -> dropping" a PC in a battle? (in terms of action economy and tactical drawbacks of such move)

Tags: dnd-5e, movement, new-gm

Some context: We're running *Dragon Heist* and having an encounter where a slow and clumsy mage must "evacuate" himself to the opposite edge of the map with the artifact.

The DM has purposely put a scary "bastion" of monsters at the edge of the map to demonstrate to the players that just running straight to the edge of the map in one turn would NOT be a viable strategy, and so the party must come up with a smarter strategy to disable the villain and his minions first...

However, the party just did some "cell counting" and came up with a plan where they'll just Haste the super-fast monk, grab the slow mage, carry him through the whole map, drop him right in front of the enemy line, the mage would then cast Misty Step to the spot behind the "bastion" and will quit the map... And all of that in just the first turn, basically breaking a potentially cool encounter that was supposed to be a "cool tactical puzzle" on how to temporarily disable the Xanathar's eye rays and weaken his minions in order to escape...

[image: Encounter map]

However, the party hasn't considered that the monk may not be able to just grab/drop the mage “for free”, without spending his actions to do that. And since the whole "forced march" plan relied very heavily on the over-encumbered monk to be able to use the Dash action... If that action must be spent on grabbing/dropping the mage, the whole "cross the whole map in one turn" plan suddenly becomes not viable at all (as intended!)…

This escalated into an intense argument with the DM. The monk, who came up with the idea, said “OK, then I’m grabbing the mage with a "Free interact with object” action!” and started to come up with some weird workaround strategies after the DM ruled that it would require an action to grab a 100+ lbs body… This easily escalated into a "railroading vs OOC" argument and I might need some DM-ing advice on that as well (but as suggested here in comments, I'd ask it separately). For this question, I'd like to ask about the game mechanics:

**Here are my questions:**

1. Is it possible for a PC to "grab -> carry -> drop" a willing creature all in one turn without spending an action? If "no", then what action resource would be required from the PC in order to perform the "grabbing" (quickly over the shoulders) and then the "dropping" (actually, not "drop on the floor" but steadily lower the PC onto the ground into a standing position)? (would these cost two full actions?)
2. Alternatively, can a mage “mount” a monk like a horse without the monk spending any action on that? If yes, what should it require? Just a half movement speed spent by the mage to mount/unmount the monk?
3. Generally, would the tactic of "grabbing the slow mage and running all over the map so that the mage could throw scary spells at the enemy's back lines" have ANY mechanical drawbacks besides just the halved speed for the monk? (The reason why I'm asking is that our campaign is happening in the Waterdeep city, so there are lots of [large open-air encounters](https://www.reddit.com/r/WaterdeepDragonHeist/comments/mms2h4/rooftop_chase_120x30/) where the spellcasting distance makes a HUGE difference. And I'd like each PC in the party to have it's own strengths and weaknesses: the monk is super fast and dodgy, the mage is dangerous but very slow and clumsy, etc...)

Comment: Your first three questions are about whether this tactic works, RAW, and if not, what would be closest.  Your last question is about encounter design and avoiding OOC conflict between players and DMs.  I think it would be worthwhile to ask point 4 as a separate question, not because it is opinion based (I think it is good-subjective and many users here may have experienced-based answers for you) but because it is a fundamentally different question, such that site policy is that it should be separated and I think you will get better answers to both questions if you do.

Comment: Ok! I'll ask the 4th question separately, it's quite important for me as a first-time D&D DM 

Comment: Do you (the DM) use the [optional variant](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/using-ability-scores#VariantEncumbrance) rules for encumbrance? This will affect the answer.

Comment: Kirt, yes, we do use the optional variant rules for encumbrance. However, I read somewhere that if you're carrying someone, your speed is halved, not just dropped by 20 feet.

Comment: UPD: I've updated the question a bit: 1) Removed most of the parts related to "DM-ing struggle" that I'll move into a separate question as Kirt has suggested. 2) Rephrased the title so that all the three concrete questions at the end will be related to it. Kindly asking to consider updating the answers. Pardon for the initial unclarity, I'm a bit new to all of this 

Comment: I'm still a little confused about the end game of all this. If the goal is to get the wizard close to the edge so they can _misty step_ off the map, 1) Why drop them? They can teleport from the mounted/carried position, 2) If casting _misty step_, they cannot have cast a "scary" spell that same round, just cantrips, 3) is the whole rest of the party supposed to fend for themselves from the creatures/assassins or do they somehow vanish one the wizard is away, 4) what is stopping the creatures/assassins from following/attacking the wizard beyond the edge of the shown map?

Comment: @MivaScott I've actually removed some parts in the text explaining the logic of this encounter in order to move it to a separate question as Kirt has suggested. But here is a quick summary:

Comment: @MivaScott 1) Monk wanted to drop the mage in order to be able to kick some owlbears after the run, on the same very turn. Also, the dropping was part of one of the "workarounds" for the plan. Also at some point the DM said that you can't cast misty step while you're being carried over the shoulder (DM ruled this way being worried about the point number 3 in my question)

Comment: @MivaScott 2) The question about the mage running around the map and casting "scary" spells at the enemy's back lines was not exactly about this particular party's move with the Misty Step, but more generally. Since our campaign is in the city, we have large open air maps, not dungeons. On such maps, the spellcasting distance really matters. And many spells require 30ft / 60ft. On these maps, enemies like Xanathar or longbow archers present a cool tactical challenge! And I didn't want the party to have a "weird tactic" of mage running around on the monk that would just destroy all of this.

Comment: @MivaScott 3) The whole hook of the campaign is that the party gets access to the Stone Of Golorr and all of the city villains are trying to get it ('cause it's basically an artifact worth 500k gold). So the Xanathar on this map would care ONLY about the mage who was the only one who was able to get the Stone's "respect". Also the villain knows that the Stone made the mage super selfish and he would not care even if his friends will be captured. So, only the mage is the target, and not dead but alive! That's why the DM said that mage leaving the map is good enough, and party took advantage :)

Comment: @MivaScott 4) the background for this encounter is that the party went to an important negotiation in the part of the city where "if you go north, there is a ghetto district where there are NO city guards, basically NO rule of law at all" and "if you go south, you'll quickly find yourself in the territory protected by the City Watch where the Xanathar would never dare to appear". Understanding the risk/reward, the party still decided to go into that ghetto district. And I thought it was a great opportunity to introduce the BBEG in-person and also give the party a challenging tactical encounter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### A good ruling considers the weight of the wizard

You have a bunch of questions wrapped up in one, so I will cover them in order:

**Is it possible for a PC to grab -> drag -> drop a willing creature all in one turn without spending an action?**

No. Technically a PC is [not an object](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/95532/what-is-considered-an-object), so you cannot use the Free Object interaction. You could use two other approaches, but either one will cost your action:

##### 1. Grappling

One way to grap and drag another creature is to grapple them (p. 195 PHB), but this will require you to take the attack action, so it costs an action, and it will also halve your speed:

> When you want to grab a creature or wrestle with it, you can use the Attack action to make a special melee attack, a grapple. (...) Using at least one free hand, you try to seize the target by making a grapple check, a Strength (Athletics) check contested by the target’s Strength (Athletics) or Dexterity (Acrobatics) check (the target chooses the ability to use). (...)
> ***Moving a Grappled Creature***. When you move, you can drag or carry the grappled creature with you, but your speed is halved, unless the creature is two or more sizes smaller than you.

Also, note that *technically* grappling is an ability check, so the target [cannot opt to fail it](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/109583/is-it-possible-to-fail-an-ability-check-on-purpose) on purpose. I however know nobody who plays it that way, as it seems clear that the grappling rules are written with an opponent in mind that tries to counteract being grappled. With a willing target and without opposition, it does not make sense to call for a contest.

The grapple rules are weird in that they ignore the weight of the target when it comes to moving the target around. Depending on your speed and the weight, even sacrificing half your movement may be faster than carrying the creature, creating a rules loophole for the effect of weight.

##### 2. Lifting and Carrying

As discussed, picking up and carrying or dragging a *willing* character may be not a great match for the grappling rules. The other way to consider this is to use the carrying and lifting rules. Shouldering a character is not one of the listed standard actions, so the general rule for actions in combat applies (page 192 PHB):

> When you take your action on your turn, you can take one of the actions presented here, an action you gained from your class or a special feature, or **an action that you improvise**. (...) When you describe an action not detailed elsewhere in the rules, **the DM tells you whether that action is
> possible** and what kind of roll you need to make, if any, to determine success or failure.

Taking a non-standard action such as shouldering another character is still an action. You may be able to carry them, but doing so consumes your action.

To see if this of any use, you need to determine the weight of the character to be carried, including their equipment, plus the weight of equipment of the carrying character, as all that matters is the total weight. The rules (p. 176 PHB) state:

> **Carrying Capacity**. Your carrying capacity is your Strength score multiplied by 15. (...) 
> ***Push, Drag, or Lift***. You can push, drag, or lift a weight in pounds up to twice your carrying capacity (or 30 times your Strength score). While pushing or dragging weight in excess of your carrying capacity,
> your speed drops to 5 feet.

Eyballing probable numbers here, the monk can use Dexterity instead of Strength for their unarmed attacks, so they are unlikely to have maximized Strength. That means the probably have at best Strength 14, or can carry 210 pounds. Neither monk nor wizard tend to wear heavy armor, so it might be possible that they can lift you up without slowing down to a crawl, but typcial equipment for adventurers with backpack, rope, bedding, rations, clothing and weapons tends to weigh quite a bit, so you'd need to check the numbers.

If you are using the Variant: Encumberance rules, the cutoffs tend to be more stringent, and this for sure will slow you down. A total weight of more than 5 times Strength will make you **encumbered**, slowing you by 10 feet, and more then 10 times Strength will make you **heavily encumbered**, slowing you by 20 feet.

**Alternatively, can a mage “mount” a monk like a horse without the monk spending his action on that? If yes, what should it require? Just a half movement speed spent by the mage to mount/unmount the monk?**

The combat rules for Mounted Combat (p. 198 PHB) say:

> A willing creature that is at least one size larger than you and that has an appropriate anatomy can serve as a mount

So this will not work unless the wizard is small (a halfling or gnome, perchance) and the monk is medium. If that is the case, it will be up to your DM to determing if riding on the shoulders qualifies as appropriate anatomy. If the DM allows it, then mounting would cost just half the wizards movement speed and no action. The monk would count as an independent mount because the rules say (198 PHB)

> Intelligent creatures, such as dragons, act independently.

Note however that mounts are *not exempt* from the encumberance rules. Common mounts such as horses are large and have enough carrying capacity for a rider and equipment, but with a character "mount", even if the DM approves, you will run into the exact same limitations discussed above under Lifting and Carrying.

**If a Hasted monk grabs a mage and runs with him all around the map, would it mean that the mage just basically got a crazy movement increase and can cast some scary spells right at the back of the enemy forces while being carried over the monk’s shoulder? What about mage not being carried, but “mounting” the monk (sitting on the shoulders)?**

The movement rules treat each comabatant's movement separately, so the wizard would benefit from the mounts or grapplers increased speed. There is nothing in the spellcasting rules that stops you from casting while mounted or grappled, as long as you fulfil the other requirements for somatic, material and verbal components.

Many of the "scary" spells however are ranged and gain little from such a tactic.

**Would that balance-breaking tactic have ANY drawbacks besides just the halved speed for the monk? (which is easily compensated with Haste+Dash and the fact that monks have a natural high speed)**

*Haste* is pretty powerful, wether you try this tactic or just leverage the increased speed and additional action. I'm not sure the tactic is balance breaking, as the rules pretty much do not allow you to execute it unless the caster is Small size, and your DM is generous. Even then, there are many costs, foremost that of a third level spell slot and concentration, and also tying up a hand for the monk if you use the grapple rules, falling off your mount if the DM allows mounting and someone manages to push the monk, the caster taking damage and losing concentration on *haste* stunning the monk for a round and nailing the vulnerable caster in the midst of enemy combatants, etc. In fact, a wizard is likely to be one of the classes benefitting the least from getting close and personal. A slow, heavily armored melee fighter that can get a large speed boost and benefit from not suffering opportunity attacks when moving around would likely benefit more than a wizard from this.

Comment: UPD: I've updated the question a bit: 1) Removed most of the parts related to "DM-ing struggle" that I'll move into a separate question as Kirt has suggested. 2) Rephrased the title so that all the three concrete questions at the end will be related to it. Kindly asking to consider updating the answers. Pardon for the initial unclarity, I'm a bit new to all of this 

Comment: Carrying capacity is the first ruling I thought of. Applying the Grappling rules to carry a willing creature seems like the wrong choice. Using a mount probably isn't the right call either, though I think it's a better choice than Grappling. I wonder if there's a reasonable case for the Powerful Build racial feature allowing you to serve as a mount for creatures the same size as you.

Answer (score 11):

(1) Rules As Written, you can't use "Interact With Object" to pick up a party member.  There's a formal definition of "object":

> For the purpose of these rules, an object is a discrete, inanimate item like a window, door, sword, book, table, chair, or stone, not a building or a vehicle that is composed of many other objects.

It's a common house-rule for DMs to allow characters to pick up other willing characters, but you don't have to allow this.

If you want to be very Rules As Written about it, the only way for one character to move another is to use an action to grapple them (and they're forced to roll to resist), and then if the grapple succeeds, to carry them at half movement speed.  On future turns, no action is required to maintain the grapple, so the monk could just keep carrying the mage.

In the past, when someone has said "hey, can I pull this other character along with me as I move?", I've treated it as an object interaction to start a grapple with a friendly target, rather than an action.

(2) The [mounted combat rules](https://5thsrd.org/combat/mounted_combat/) say:

> A willing creature that is at least one size larger than you and that has an appropriate anatomy can serve as a mount, using the following rules.

It's a DM ruling whether "riding on a monk's shoulders" counts as appropriate anatomy, but unless the mage is a halfling, the monk probably isn't one size larger.

(3) Most of the time, spellcasting isn't really limited by range, so it doesn't seem game-breaking for the mage to have better movement.  Note, also, that the mage usually doesn't want to be in the same place as the monk.  If you did allow the monk to carry the mage somehow, it probably wouldn't break anything, in general.

(4) It sounds like your players had a lot of fun solving the puzzle you gave them, except for the part at the end where you vetoed the solution they'd been so excited about.

My advice is: be happy when the players are engaged with your adventure, and try not to veto stuff they're excited about.

For this specific scenario, it seems like there might have been something you could have said about the fate of the rest of the group.  For example you might have said: "hey, it looks like this plan involves the monk ending his turn next to a bunch of enraged owlbears and ninjas, so the mage is likely to get away but the monk might die, are you sure you want to do this?"

Comment: Thanks! Some clarification on the 4th point: I initially told the party that it would be good enough if only the artifact holder will  evacuate from the map ('cause the only thing the villain cares is getting the artifact and he's not interested in wasting time on the others)... So when the mage was about to hit the edge of the map I also told the party that if the monk will be finishing the encounter right in front of the enraged owlbears, you might lose them, exactly like you've suggested. Then the monk just left easily because of his mobile feat and high acrobatics :)

Comment: (1) so, could you please clarify what should be done instead of the "interact with an object" then? The "Improvise action"? Or maybe even a grapple "attack" action?

Comment: (3) actually, in our city campaign setting (Waterdeep city), we do not have a lot of dungeons with small rooms, but rather a lot of open space city encounters like the rooftop chase: https://www.reddit.com/r/WaterdeepDragonHeist/comments/mms2h4/rooftop_chase_120x30/. For these and for the very encounter I'm mentioning in this post, spell range is a real think to consider. With a beholder being able to reach at 120 ft with it's range, spell range of 30 ft and even 60 ft is a HUGE limitation that presents another puzzle for the party to solve. Same for other city streets encounters.

Comment: (3) Considering the previous point about the type of encounters where spell range matters A LOT, could you suggest any reasonable challenges that would make the "monk-flash carrying a mage" a more like a tradeoff decision, not a default option? Or you'd just say "let it go, the mage could get a Hasted steed and get the same maneuverability anyway?" But the steed would not have the same "contingency escape features" (the monk has the Mobile feat that allows him to avoid opportunity attacks as well as a much higher AC/HP than the steed)

Comment: Okay, I've updated my answer.  Rules As Written, the monk can use an action to grapple the mage, and from that point forward can just carry the mage at half move speed wherever he goes.  I recommend that you let it go.

Comment: UPD: Dan, I've updated the question a bit: 1) Removed most of the parts related to "DM-ing struggle" that I'll move into a separate question as Kirt has suggested. 2) Rephrased the title so that all the three concrete questions at the end will be related to it. Kindly asking to consider updating the answers. Pardon for the initial unclarity, I'm a bit new to all of this 

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I would disallow it.  Taking turns sequentially is a workaround for the fact that doing them simultaneously would be a nightmare.  The tactics you are proposing seriously break this abstraction.  We have three actions which must happen **sequentially**--the monk gets hasted, the monk carries the mage, the mage casts misty step.

I also have a problem with casually scooping up in passing something that's much of their carrying capacity.