# Can I Charm a creature I’ve summoned with Conjure Fey, to keep them in check if my concentration breaks?

Tags: dnd-5e, druid, summoning, charmed

If I summon a creature with [Conjure Fey](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/conjure-fey) first, and then cast [Charm Monster](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/charm-monster) on it, would that prevent my CR 6+ Beast/Fey from attacking my group should my concentration later be broken?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### This works in theory

The *conjure fey* spell does not impose the charmed condition, the creature simply obeys you. Thus it can be affected by *charm monster* and gain the charmed condition from it. When your concentration breaks, the charm will still be in effect, preventing the creature from attacking you.

There are a few things that have to be noted:

- The charmed condition does not explicitly protect your allies, although it does give you Advantage to persuade the creature not to attack them.
- The creature has to fail the saving throw of *charm monster*.
- This will depend on your DM, but you might not be able to *tell* whether they failed the save or not. The creature is already obedient, being charmed might not be noticeable.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! In response to your 2nd/3rd points, assuming I have complete control over the creature while I hold concentration on the Conjure Fey spell, can I command them to not resist (save) my subsequent Charm Monster Spell?

Comment: @Morgan Creatures cannot voluntarily fail a save, unless the effect explicitly states so. So such a command cannot be followed.

Comment: What Szega said. See here: [Can you choose to fail a saving throw?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/47487/can-you-choose-to-fail-a-saving-throw)