# If a sorcerer casts the Banishment spell on a PC while in Avernus, does the PC return to their home plane?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, planes

I wanted to make it difficult for the party to leave Avernus and return to their home plane, but I have realized that one of the party members could just use the *banishment* spell a number of times to get the party to return to their home plane.

Is my understanding of the spell correct?

Comment: [Highly related.](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/47436/15469)

Comment: Also related: [If I cast Banishment on myself while in a demiplane, where exactly do I exit?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/116960/if-i-cast-banishment-on-myself-while-in-a-demiplane-where-exactly-do-i-exit)

Answer (score 34):

### Yes, but there is a caveat

Firstly [*banishment*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/banishment) requires a Charisma saving throw which the party members must [fail on](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/47487/can-you-choose-to-fail-a-saving-throw?rq=1), but given enough time/spell slots this wouldn't be a problem, merely an inconvenience.

Given failures and nothing to stop the spell prematurely, they will be sent to their home plane, as per the relevant except from the spell:

> If the target is native to a different plane of existence than the one you're on, the target is banished with a faint popping noise, returning to its home plane. If the spell ends before 1 minute has passed, the target reappears in the space it left or in the nearest unoccupied space if that space is occupied. Otherwise, the target doesn't return.

However *banishment* makes to mention of where on the relevant plane the target appears, leaving room for the DM to choose. Most of the time (i.e. normal castings of this spell on demons, elementals etc.) that location doesn't matter, but with PC's it does. So you could rule, preferably before the spell is cast (unless you like being mean and punishing to your players), that they will end up on separate, random places on that plane with no knowledge of where they or the others are. Using this ruling will replace their current problem of being stuck on Avernus, with the problem of being stuck on random locations on the Material plane (assuming they're from there). This latter problem will be harsh on any non-spellcasters and on spellcasters who haven't got access to teleporation and/or divination spells to find the others again.

Comment: Great answer, and just to highlight part of your answer I feel is important: Don't surprise your players with rules-"gotcha"s like "now that you're back on the material plane, you realize that you have no idea where banishment actually placed you. Your friends could be hundreds of miles away, or more."

Comment: The second half of the description gives an option:  Some form of curse or effect that always causes the Banishment spell to end within 50 seconds, returning the target to Avernus?

Comment: The obvious answer for non spellcasters is to wait for the spellcasters to pick them up :)

Comment: I like this answer and also if this happens it could make **a lot** of extra work for the GM who now has 3, 4, 5, 6 or however many PCs there are, separate adventures to manage. I think this approach would work best if you tell the PCs ahead of time they could end up in the middle of the ocean, in the tundra, or some other place where death might be imminent. In other words let them know they could die if they do this And really use this to convince them not to go this route.

Comment: Especially considering the Material plane largely consists of cold, dark, space. I'd _shudder_ at the thought of being banished back to the Material plane. Banishing is not a pleasant experience.

Comment: The intent of the spell (from the second paragraph of the spell) is clearly meant to avoid harm coming to the creature since it banishes it to a "harmless demiplane")

Comment: @illustro I'm not sure teleporting the adventurers back from another plane is the intended use of the spell either though

Comment: Banishing creatures to a plane of existence that isn't the current one is exactly the point of this spell. Whether or not the creature being banished would regard that as beneficial...that is an entirely different question.

Comment: Even if you could guarantee that you'd be banished back to the same planet you came from - if it's anything like Earth, that would give you a 2/3rds chance of winding up in the middle of the ocean.  Hope you can swim and/or conjure up something that floats when you arrive...

Comment: I would advise that if you banish them somewhere, make it a place that they might have access to a means of teleportational travel and a way to know where their friends are, i.e. a mage tower with a permanent magic circle, or a scrying service. Feel free to charge them as much as you want, though, for using this loophole.